# Bootstrap Grid System Unexpected Results On Phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was making a web page using the bootstrap grid system on my old laptop with 720p resolution with the idea that it would still fit on higher resolutions. I wasn't attempting to make to work on smaller (low res devices),  I used col-md for lining things up.

Anyways, it looks great on 720p laptop and my 1080p desktop, but whe I use my phone which is also 1080p in landscape everything is squished together (even when holding it in the landscape view).

Shouldn't holding the phone in landscape give a nearly identical view as my desktop of the same resolution? It certainly shouldn't be more squished than my even lower resolution labtop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

720p is not the same thing as viewport width. 720p is just 720 horizontal lines of resolution. It says nothing about the pixel dimension.

Bootstrap uses pixels to determine breakpoints. The first mobile breakpoint is at 768px;

Your phones display has a very different viewport pixel count, and you wont be able to replicate this accurately on a desktop display.

Design for desktop for any viewports over 768px wide, and design for mobile for any viewports less than 768px.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'd say to try and use col-sm as well, and before testing on your phone you can open chrome dev tools and turn on responsive to test things out on different viewports.